# Android Crypto++ compiling by command line, GNUmakefile

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, crypto++

I have a problem to make appriopriate GNUmakefile, which should create Crypto++ library for Android. I am using this [tutorial](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_%28Command_Line%29), and I'm stuck on patching makefile. Where can I find file GNUmakefile-android.patch which there is mentioned? I've tryied to add manually lines to file but I am not sure I am doing it correct. Now my GNUmakefile looks like this:

```
CXXFLAGS = -DNDEBUG -g -O2
# -O3 fails to link on Cygwin GCC version 4.5.3
# -fPIC is supported. Please report any breakage of -fPIC as a bug.
# CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
# the following options reduce code size, but breaks link or makes link very slow on some systems
# CXXFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
# LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections
ARFLAGS = -cr   # ar needs the dash on OpenBSD
RANLIB = ranlib
CP = cp
MKDIR = mkdir
EGREP = egrep
UNAME = $(shell uname)
ISX86 = $(shell uname -m | $(EGREP) -c "i.86|x86|i86|amd64")
IS_SUN_CC = $(shell $(CXX) -V 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "CC: Sun")
IS_LINUX = $(shell $(CXX) -dumpmachine 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "linux")
IS_MINGW = $(shell $(CXX) -dumpmachine 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "mingw")
CLANG_COMPILER = $(shell $(CXX) --version 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -i -c "clang version")

# Set in the environment
ifeq ($(IS_CROSS_COMPILE),1)
  ISX86=0
  IS_LINUX=0
  IS_MINGW=0
  IS_DARWIN=0
  UNAME=CrossCompile
endif

# Default prefix for make install
ifeq ($(PREFIX),)
PREFIX = /usr
endif

ifeq ($(CXX),gcc)   # for some reason CXX is gcc on cygwin 1.1.4
CXX = g++
endif


ifeq ($(IS_ANDROID),1)
  CPP=arm-linux-androideabi-cpp
  CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++
  AR=arm-linux-androideabi-ar
  RANLIB=arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
  LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld

  CXXFLAGS += -fPIC -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM --sysroot=$(ANDROID_SYSROOT) -I$(ANDROID_STL_INC)
  LDLIBS += $(ANDROID_STL_LIB)
endif

#if defined(__ANDROID__)
# include <sys/select.h>
#endif

ifeq ($(ISX86),1)

GCC42_OR_LATER = $(shell $(CXX) -v 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "^gcc version (4.[2-9]|[5-9])")
INTEL_COMPILER = $(shell $(CXX) --version 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "\(ICC\)")
ICC111_OR_LATER = $(shell $(CXX) --version 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "\(ICC\) ([2-9][0-9]|1[2-9]|11\.[1-9])")
GAS210_OR_LATER = $(shell $(CXX) -xc -c /dev/null -Wa,-v -o/dev/null 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "GNU assembler version (2\.[1-9][0-9]|[3-9])")
GAS217_OR_LATER = $(shell $(CXX) -xc -c /dev/null -Wa,-v -o/dev/null 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "GNU assembler version (2\.1[7-9]|2\.[2-9]|[3-9])")
GAS219_OR_LATER = $(shell $(CXX) -xc -c /dev/null -Wa,-v -o/dev/null 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "GNU assembler version (2\.19|2\.[2-9]|[3-9])")

ifneq ($(GCC42_OR_LATER),0)
ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
CXXFLAGS += -arch x86_64 -arch i386
else
CXXFLAGS += -march=native
endif
endif

ifneq ($(INTEL_COMPILER),0)
CXXFLAGS += -wd68 -wd186 -wd279 -wd327
ifeq ($(ICC111_OR_LATER),0)
# "internal error: backend signals" occurs on some x86 inline assembly with ICC 9 and some x64 inline assembly with ICC 11.0
# if you want to use Crypto++'s assembly code with ICC, try enabling it on individual files
CXXFLAGS += -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM
endif
endif

ifeq ($(GAS210_OR_LATER),0) # .intel_syntax wasn't supported until GNU assembler 2.10
CXXFLAGS += -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM
else
ifeq ($(GAS217_OR_LATER),0)
CXXFLAGS += -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_SSSE3
else
ifeq ($(GAS219_OR_LATER),0)
CXXFLAGS += -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_AESNI
endif
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME),SunOS)
CXXFLAGS += -Wa,--divide    # allow use of "/" operator
endif
endif

endif   # ISX86

ifeq ($(UNAME),)    # for DJGPP, where uname doesn't exist
CXXFLAGS += -mbnu210
else
CXXFLAGS += -pipe
endif

ifeq ($(IS_MINGW),1)
LDLIBS += -lws2_32
endif

ifeq ($(IS_LINUX),1)
LDFLAGS += -pthread
ifneq ($(shell uname -i | $(EGREP) -c "(_64|d64)"),0)
M32OR64 = -m64
endif
endif

ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
AR = libtool
ARFLAGS = -static -o
CXX = c++
IS_GCC2 = $(shell $(CXX) -v 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c gcc-932)
ifeq ($(IS_GCC2),1)
CXXFLAGS += -fno-coalesce-templates -fno-coalesce-static-vtables
LDLIBS += -lstdc++
LDFLAGS += -flat_namespace -undefined suppress -m
endif
endif

ifeq ($(UNAME),SunOS)
LDLIBS += -lnsl -lsocket
M32OR64 = -m$(shell isainfo -b)
endif

ifneq ($(CLANG_COMPILER),0)
CXXFLAGS += -Wno-tautological-compare
endif

ifneq ($(IS_SUN_CC),0)  # override flags for CC Sun C++ compiler
CXXFLAGS = -DNDEBUG -O -g0 -native -template=no%extdef $(M32OR64)
LDFLAGS =
AR = $(CXX)
ARFLAGS = -xar -o
RANLIB = true
SUN_CC10_BUGGY = $(shell $(CXX) -V 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "CC: Sun .* 5\.10 .* (2009|2010/0[1-4])")
ifneq ($(SUN_CC10_BUGGY),0)
# -DCRYPTOPP_INCLUDE_VECTOR_CC is needed for Sun Studio 12u1 Sun C++ 5.10 SunOS_i386 128229-02 2009/09/21 and was fixed in May 2010
# remove it if you get "already had a body defined" errors in vector.cc
CXXFLAGS += -DCRYPTOPP_INCLUDE_VECTOR_CC
endif
endif

SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)
ifeq ($(SRCS),)             # workaround wildcard function bug in GNU Make 3.77
SRCS = $(shell echo *.cpp)
endif

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
# test.o needs to be after bench.o for cygwin 1.1.4 (possible ld bug?)
TESTOBJS = bench.o bench2.o test.o validat1.o validat2.o validat3.o adhoc.o datatest.o regtest.o fipsalgt.o dlltest.o
LIBOBJS = $(filter-out $(TESTOBJS),$(OBJS))

DLLSRCS = algebra.cpp algparam.cpp asn.cpp basecode.cpp cbcmac.cpp channels.cpp cryptlib.cpp des.cpp dessp.cpp dh.cpp dll.cpp dsa.cpp ec2n.cpp eccrypto.cpp ecp.cpp eprecomp.cpp files.cpp filters.cpp fips140.cpp fipstest.cpp gf2n.cpp gfpcrypt.cpp hex.cpp hmac.cpp integer.cpp iterhash.cpp misc.cpp modes.cpp modexppc.cpp mqueue.cpp nbtheory.cpp oaep.cpp osrng.cpp pch.cpp pkcspad.cpp pubkey.cpp queue.cpp randpool.cpp rdtables.cpp rijndael.cpp rng.cpp rsa.cpp sha.cpp simple.cpp skipjack.cpp strciphr.cpp trdlocal.cpp
DLLOBJS = $(DLLSRCS:.cpp=.export.o)
LIBIMPORTOBJS = $(LIBOBJS:.o=.import.o)
TESTIMPORTOBJS = $(TESTOBJS:.o=.import.o)
DLLTESTOBJS = dlltest.dllonly.o

all: cryptest.exe
static: libcryptopp.a
dynamic: libcryptopp.so

test: cryptest.exe
    ./cryptest.exe v

clean:
    -$(RM) cryptest.exe libcryptopp.a libcryptopp.so $(LIBOBJS) $(TESTOBJS) cryptopp.dll libcryptopp.dll.a libcryptopp.import.a cryptest.import.exe dlltest.exe $(DLLOBJS) $(LIBIMPORTOBJS) $(TESTI MPORTOBJS) $(DLLTESTOBJS)

install:
    $(MKDIR) -p $(PREFIX)/include/cryptopp $(PREFIX)/lib $(PREFIX)/bin
    -$(CP) *.h $(PREFIX)/include/cryptopp
    -$(CP) *.a $(PREFIX)/lib
    -$(CP) *.so $(PREFIX)/lib
    -$(CP) *.exe $(PREFIX)/bin

remove:
    -$(RM) -rf $(PREFIX)/include/cryptopp
    -$(RM) $(PREFIX)/lib/libcryptopp.a
    -$(RM) $(PREFIX)/lib/libcryptopp.so
    -$(RM) $(PREFIX)/bin/cryptest.exe

libcryptopp.a: $(LIBOBJS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(LIBOBJS)
    $(RANLIB) $@

libcryptopp.so: $(LIBOBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBOBJS)

cryptest.exe: libcryptopp.a $(TESTOBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(TESTOBJS) ./libcryptopp.a $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

nolib: $(OBJS)      # makes it faster to test changes
    $(CXX) -o ct $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

dll: cryptest.import.exe dlltest.exe

cryptopp.dll: $(DLLOBJS)
    $(CXX) -shared -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(DLLOBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -Wl,--out-implib=libcryptopp.dll.a

libcryptopp.import.a: $(LIBIMPORTOBJS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(LIBIMPORTOBJS)
    $(RANLIB) $@

cryptest.import.exe: cryptopp.dll libcryptopp.import.a $(TESTIMPORTOBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(TESTIMPORTOBJS) -L. -lcryptopp.dll -lcryptopp.import $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

dlltest.exe: cryptopp.dll $(DLLTESTOBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(DLLTESTOBJS) -L. -lcryptopp.dll $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

adhoc.cpp: adhoc.cpp.proto
ifeq ($(wildcard adhoc.cpp),)
    cp adhoc.cpp.proto adhoc.cpp
else
    touch adhoc.cpp
endif

%.dllonly.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DCRYPTOPP_DLL_ONLY -c $< -o $@

%.import.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DCRYPTOPP_IMPORTS -c $< -o $@

%.export.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DCRYPTOPP_EXPORTS -c $< -o $@

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
```

When I execute command 'make static dynamic cryptest.exe' I get this error:

```
g++ -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -march=native -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM -pipe -c shacal2.cpp
In file included from cryptlib.h:83:0,
                 from seckey.h:8,
                 from shacal2.h:7,
                 from shacal2.cpp:9:
stdcpp.h:9:20: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stddef.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
GNUmakefile:233: polecenia dla obiektu 'shacal2.o' nie powiodły się
make: *** [shacal2.o] Błąd 1
```

I am using cygwin to compile this. I would be grateful for help.

Comment: how did you make out with this?

Comment: I was looking at the Crypto++ makefile, and I did *not* see any Cygwin dependent defines (but I might have missed something obvious). What preprocessor macros does Cygwin set to distinguish itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can I find file GNUmakefile-android.patch which there is mentioned?

The downloads are at the bottom of the page.

---

> Now my GNUmakefile looks like this:

```
> # Set in the environment
> ifeq ($(IS_CROSS_COMPILE),1)
>   ISX86=0
>   IS_LINUX=0
>   IS_MINGW=0
>   IS_DARWIN=0
>   UNAME=CrossCompile
> endif
```

This unsets the "host" flags used by the Makefile. Otherwise, Crypto++ will set `CXXFLAGS` for the host (i.e, your Desktop computer), and not the target (i.e., your Android device).

Next you need the `CXXFLAGS` for the target. From the same tutorial:

```
ifeq ($(IS_ANDROID),1)
  CPP=arm-linux-androideabi-cpp
  CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++
  AR=arm-linux-androideabi-ar
  RANLIB=arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
  LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld

  CXXFLAGS += -fPIC -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM --sysroot=$(ANDROID_SYSROOT) -I$(ANDROID_STL_INC)
  LDLIBS += $(ANDROID_STL_LIB)
endif
```

There's also a couple of one/two liners to ensure some Android specific includes are found.

---

The last question should be: where is `IS_CROSS_COMPILE`, `IS_ANDROID`, `ANDROID_SYSROOT` and friends set? The answer is in `setenv-android.sh`.

The download for `setenv-android.sh` is at the bottom of the page, too.

---

> When I execute command 'make static dynamic cryptest.exe' I get this error:
>
> ```
> g++ -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -march=native -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM -pipe -c shacal2.cpp
> ```

You did not run `setenv-android.sh`. As the tutorial states, the compiler command that you should see:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM -pipe -fPIC
--sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -I/opt/android-ndk-r9/sources/
cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/ -c 3way.cpp
...
```

---

> I am using cygwin to compile this.

The tutorial was written against the Android NDK. The procedures and scripts were tested on Linux and Mac OS X.

The NDK should work with Cygwin; and Crypto++ should work with Cygwin. However, the combination of Android and Cygwin on Windows was never tested, and the Makefile might need more tuning. I just don't know because its was never tested.

Can you set up a Linux virtual machine in Windows? It might be easier to complete the process.

---

> When I execute command 'make static dynamic cryptest.exe'...

For completeness, `cryptest.exe` will fail if its executed on the host computer. You should push `cryptest.exe` to the device via `adb` (along with the test vectors), and then execute it on the device. I think the tutorial covers that too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, it was problem with environment variables (still is). I haven't noted that setenv-android.sh haven't set all environment variables which should be. I did it manually but then compiler scream that he cannot find another headers. So for now I gave up and I just copied headers and *.cpp files to JNI folder and prepare appriopriate Android.mk to use it. Maybe when I will have some time I will try to do it on Linux as you said.

Comment: "I haven't noted that `setenv-android.sh` haven't set all environment variables ..." - make sure you use a leading dot "`.`" when executing the script to apply the changes to the current shell. That is, `. ./setenv-android.sh`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem compiling, and now seem to have successfully compiled on cygwin.  AFter following the instructions referenced by the previous answer (link [http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_(Command_Line)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_%28Command_Line%29)), I then ran into the issue of g++ being unable to locate the headers.

Courtesy of g++'s handy -v option, I found the problem.  The issue is that g++ is unable to parse the **"/opt/android-ndk-r9d/etc/..."** paths within the cygwin environment.  Adding the -v option to the GNUMakeFile patch of the **CXXFLAGS** showed that both the **$ANDROID_STL_INC** and the **$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN** variables set by the setenv-android.sh script both fell under
"Ignoring nonexistent directory ..."

I fixed this by replacing the **$(ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN)** and the **$(ANDROID_STL_INC)** with the **WINDOWS** style paths (e.g. **C:/cygwin/c/opt/android-ndk-r9d/etc/...**) and the libraries compiled.  Hurray.

However, cryptest.exe seems to have failed.  Will update as I fix more.

**UPDATE**

Same issue, the **$ANDROID_STL_LIB** set by setenv-android.sh also can't be parsed.  Replaced the **LBLIBS** in the GNUMakeFile with the **WINDOWS** style path C:/cygwin/c/opt/android-ndk-r9d/etc/.../libstlport_shared.so and full compilation.